# Number sign/hash symbol (#) breaks code

Tags: amazon-web-services

Someone made a web page that pulls event data from eventbrite, writes it on an SVG, uses Amazon Web services, and saves it as a PDF to create fliers.

It works here: www.ilovemylaser.com/fliers.html.

However, if I use '#' in the address line, it breaks, so for the San Diego ones onward, I've replaced '#' with 'No.'.

If you look at www.admaticonsulting.com/resources/fliers2.html, I've used '#2'. If you click the flier, you'll see that the city, venue name, time, state and zip are missing. Compare that to the Thousand Oaks flier from the first link.

This line is in the code, and I'm pretty sure it's the issue:

```
var output = "<p><a href=\"h t t p ://ec2-52-42-194-56.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws. com/task.php?date=" + date + "&staddress=" + venue + "&venue=" + ven3 + "&city=" + city + "&region=" + region + "&postal_code=" + postal_code +"&time="+ time + "\">" + date + " - " + city + "</a><br></p>";
```

Now I can't post more than 2 links, but if you click any flier link, you'll see it will display one link, then resolve to something another.

Pretty sure the # is affecting this. Also, there are spaces in the "resolved link" of the ones that have '#'. There aren't any spaces in the ones that don't

How can I use # and not have missing data on the flier?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `encodeURIComponent` to encode each the the query string values:

```
var output = "<p><a href=\"h t t p ://ec2-52-42-194-56.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws. com/task.php?date=" + encodeURIComponent(date) + "&staddress=" + encodeURIComponent(venue) + "&venue=" + encodeURIComponent(ven3) + "&city=" + encodeURIComponent(city) + "&region=" + encodeURIComponent(region) + "&postal_code=" + encodeURIComponent(postal_code) +"&time="+ encodeURIComponent(time) + "\">" + date + " - " + city + "</a><br></p>";
```

Answer (score 0):

A # in an URL begins a [Fragment Identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier) which is handled locally by the browser or other client; it is **not included in the HTTP request sent to the server**, and thus cannot be used in any processing on the server. [To include a 'reserved' character as data in a URL you must encode it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Percent-encoding_reserved_characters). Note that link is `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Percent-encoding_reserved_characters` and when you click on it the page obtained from the server is `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding` then your browser positions to the anchor tag for `Percent-encoding_reserved_characters`.

Comment: I remember now, I used that before. Thank you.