# Jersey GET request behaviour

Tags: java, jersey-2.0

I am using Jersey 2.x.
I have a GET Request with the following method signature :

```
    @GET
    @Path("/size/file/{fileName}")
    @Produces("application/json")

    public Response getFileSize(@PathParam("fileName") String filename,
            @Context ContainerRequestContext crc) {
    ......
    ......
}
```

I hit my URL in the following two ways :

1. http://localhost:8083/sample/size/file/hello_____
2. http://localhost:8083/sample/size/file/hello#$

please notice the `#$` in the 2nd request.

When I check the parameter in GET Request using IDE Watcher , for the first request the `fileName` is `hello_____` and output is invalid file name.

For the second one when I checked the parameter I found it as `hello`, I wonder where the `#$` gone ?

I have the following questions with the above context.

1. Why the GET request accepted `_____` but not `#$` (in the backend)?
2. What happened to `#$` did the jersey cleared the special characters itself ?
3. I tried passing `@` then the output is invalid file name, why this time @ is not cleared as in case of `#$` ?
4. Is this is a sql injection and can affect my API. If yes then how to handle such scenarios. What actions to take to prevent this ?

I hope I am clear with my questions.

Thank you

Comment: did you try to urlencode the url?

Comment: see http://webdesign.about.com/od/forms/a/url_encoding.htm for reserved characters

Comment: Weirdly, dupe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40814925/number-sign-hash-symbol-breaks-code

Comment: I tried adding `%24`(url encoded) instead of `#` in the back end then I get the value `#` but when I pass `#` directly it is cleared ? I am not able to understand how things are working.I am totally confused.